# Does the Jerusalem Bible teach that Adam had a wife before Eve?

Tags: adam-and-eve

A Friend told me that the Jerusalem Bible says that Adam had a wife before Eve, she was only together with the devil and not with Adam, so God took her away and created Eve from Adam's Rib.

I am a Catholic of Heart and do not know the Jerusalem Bible. Can you please enlighten me? My grandson's girlfriend is telling these stories, and I have the feeling this family tries to brainwash him.

Please help!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You can read it for yourself here: http://www.unz.org/Pub/Bible-1966v01-00015

Comment: The account of creation in Genesis chapters 1 and 2 seems to be the same in the Jerusalem bible as in others. I don't think this relates to that specific translation. There is a (non-biblical) tradition, that some may accept, that Adam had another wife before Eve. It is based partly on the fact that there are two versions of the creation of humanity, first "male and female" in Chapter 1, then the more detailed version in chapter 2. http://judaism.about.com/od/jewishculture/a/Where-Does-The-Legend-Of-Lilith-Come-From.htm seems to be a fair explanation, though without references.

Answer (score 2):

To start with Google Jerusalem Bible and Genesis 1.  The account is the same as NIV and KJV.  The story of another wife before Eve is an old one about Lillith,  It is not Biblical in anyway I forgot where the story is at the moment.  But then this lady becomes a demon later.    So  Nothing Biblical at all.